# Is it safe to trap for "Invalid Date"

Tags: javascript, date, error-handling

Using JavaScript, I am testing for a valid date similar to the following...

```
var d = new Date("00:00 2015-02-20"); 
if(d != "Invalid Date"){
 alert("Nice date");
}else{
 alert("Bad date");
}
```

This script works fine since the JS engine spits out the error message "Invalid Date" if/when a variable is evaluated and has an invalid date value. However, I'm concerned that the error message "Invalid Date" is not consistent across all browsers and/or locale settings.

On a side note: I noticed that iOS browsers cannot parse the "HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd" string format, but desktop browsers are fine with the parsing the same string format. Bummer.

Comment: I would suggest using a library such as moment.js for the validity check, in addition you will have a bunch of other useful things that might be handy for manipulation/conversion

Comment: What's up with the down-votes? Is my question not legitimate?

Comment: While you might rely on invalid Dates having a time value of NaN, you should never rely on Date.parse to correctly parse date strings. There are many that will be parsed differently in different implementations, where some will return a "valid" date that is not the value you expect, while others may return an invalid Date while yet others might throw errors (even for "valid" date strings).

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be safer to check it against `NaN`.

```
date.valueOf() !== NaN
```

Comment: Noting that according to [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-todatestring), if the time value is NaN, *Date.prototype.toString* returns "Invalid Date". However, not all browsers in use support ECMAScript 2015 and previously *Date.prototype.toString* was entirely implementation dependent (and still mostly is).